# Promote Artifact failing in declarative Jenkins Core Pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, artifactory

My team recently migrated repositories to GitHub, hence the main branch name is changed.  When running the Jenkins Core Pipeline for prod deployment in the new branch, the build versions are restarted from *.1 instead of continuing from the previous build number. Hence promote Artifact is failing due to overwrite. What can be done to continue from previous build number?

When tried with regular deployment, it failed with error -

```
Unable to promote Artifact because Item already exists in releases local. Overwrite not allowed.
```